# how to configure dns for activedirectory located on different server

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory

when we install active directory on 2k8 by dcpromo we get an option for installing dns.when we install dns with active direcory, the dns get automatically configured. but when we install active directory without a dns and the dns server is located in another server. how we will configure dns for the active directory domain installed on different server.

havean attention to it reply soon

thanking you

Answer (score 1):

In the case where you're setting up a brand new domain and NOT setting up DNS on the machine you are DCPROMO-ing, there are some requirements for that DNS server. The DNS server will need:

- A DNS Zone set up for the AD Domain you will be creating. If you're creating a domain on `ad.dir.local` the DNS server will need a correctly set up zone for `ad.dir.local`.
- The DNS server *must*(1) support Dynamic DNS.
- The machine undergoing DCPROMO needs to have this DNS server set as its primary.

The other DNS server can be another Microsoft DNS or a BIND DNS server. Whatever it is, it needs to do the above. It's also a good idea, though not required, to host the reverse-lookup domains on that server as well.

(1) - Yes, you can do Static DNS but it is very annoyingly easy to screw up. Stick with dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

You just setup the non-DNS server to use the correct DNS server? There's also synchronization going on (do check the setup and replication, tomb-stoning is a nasty thing with subtle side-effects) between the 'master' AD and the backup/'slave AD.